# how to create javascript eventlistner for attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery

in jquery, I can easily create a event using attributes. here is the sample code.

```
$('body').on('mouseenter', '[email]', function(){})
```

My html tag is something like this.

`<span class="zF" email="internal@xyz.com" name="internal">internal</span>`

But I don't find any solution how can I do it using javascript.

does anyone know how to add event listener for an attribute using javascript?

Comment: Vanilla JS selectors can select elements with attributes just fine. Eg `target.closest('[email], a[href^="mailto:"]')` will give you an ancestor of the target which matches at least one of those attributes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `querySelector()`:

```js
document.querySelector('[email]').addEventListener('mouseenter', doFunction);

document.querySelector(' a[href^="mailto:"]').addEventListener('mouseenter', doFunction);

function doFunction() {
  console.log('hover');
}
```

```html
<span email="someEmail"> Hover to email </span>
<a href="mailto:somemail@gmail.com"> Hover to href </a>
```

Using `querySelectorAll()`

```js
var elem = document.querySelectorAll('[email], a[href^="mailto:"]');
for(var i=0; i<elem.length; i++) {
  elem[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', doFunction);
}

function doFunction() {
  console.log(this.innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<span email="someEmail"> Hover to email </span>
<a href="mailto:somemail@gmail.com"> Hover to href </a>
```

Comment: can i use multiple queryselector in single condition?

Comment: @KetanModi yes you can. Check the updated answer.